# How to flip or mirror pose animation

Tags: animation, rigging

With the small animation my character bending to the right side and stand straight. I want after he stand straight should bend in the left side same as it was in the right hand as if its walking on the rope.

[image]

Any suggestion or help how to flip my animation and make similar from right to left. Thanks

Comment: How about flipping the pose? Ctrl-C + Ctrl-Shift-V

Comment: @quiliup sorry did not work

Comment: It only works if the bones have the correct names, i.e. ending with .l/.r or _l/_r or similar for left and right. Are the bones names correct?

Comment: @quiliup ctl-c + ctl-shift-v did not work but it work this way. 1st Ctl+c copy 2nd ctl+v paste 3rd ctl+shift+v (paste the stored pose on the current pose)

Comment: @quiliup This is the final result https://imgur.com/gallery/4cvHkaP

Comment: So thats it? The problem is solved? May I write an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can also flip a pose by doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> then press <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, or <kbd>Z</kbd>, accordingly. Remember to *save* it as a new *keyframe* if you want it to save.